# Не запускается стандартная консоль c++ Visual Studio

Tags: c++, консоль

Не запускается стандартная консоь с++ в VS

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

[image: Скрин студии]
Похоже не хватает каких то компонентов, не подскажите как можно пофиксить проблему?

Comment: попробуйте вот это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42777424/visual-studio-2017-errors-on-standard-headers - если не поможет, опишите детально как пришли к такой ошибке - обновляли студию, редактировали код, ели пиццу перед этим:)

Comment: Пока не помогло, поставил SDK на версию ниже, теперь при сборке проекта вылезает ошибка, что как раз нет этого SDK (Который я установил), пробовал перенацелить проект на него, ошибка не исчезает, попробую переустановить студию